# Resources for learning "modern" web architecture patterns using python?

Tags: javascript, json, web-applications

I've heard one modern approach is a JSON-emitting back-end rendered with JavaScript/JavaScript templates front-end. I'd love to learn more about this architectural pattern, as well as other modern web architecture patterns. What are some good resources for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember this one from Google IO: Writing HTML5 apps with Google App Engine, Google Closure Library and Clojure

http://www.slideshare.net/smartrevolution/writing-html5-apps-with-google-app-engine-google-closure-library-and-clojure